# How to copy a folder from remote machine to my system using ssh or any other way

Tags: ssh, rhel, directory, cp, remote

Hi I need to copy a folder of size 885 MB from a remote machine to my system using ssh and port no is 1500

What is the command I can use to accomplish this

path of remote folder is

```
/u001/app/oracle/product/frmsrv/Nayifat/finnone
```

and I need to copy the finnone folder to my system

Answer (score 4):

Try `scp` or `rsync` over ssh,

```
scp -P 1500 -r name@host:/u001/app/oracle/product/frmsrv/Nayifat/finnone .
```

Comment: Thanks dear. I finally did it. I used this command **scp -rP1500 emerg@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/u001/app/oracle/product/frmsrv/Nayifat/finnone /home/umair/Finnone**   And i forgot to mention the port no in my question so i updated my question.