# i want to copy a directory from my local system to a remote machine using rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, cp, scp

I have a file on under my local machine with the name `codes.examples` and I want to copy it to a remote machine under the directory `~ahmet` using the command `rsync` and `ssh` knowing that remote machine using this port `ssh -p 45688`

how can I write a command to do that

Comment: What have you tried (including reading the man page which basically has an example for remote copy over ssh)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a folder from remote machine to my system using ssh or any other way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57627/how-to-copy-a-folder-from-remote-machine-to-my-system-using-ssh-or-any-other-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 45688' codes.examples 'user@remote:~ahmet/'
```

The `-e` (`--rsh`) option is for specifying what command to use to open the connection to the remote machine.

You could also use `scp`:

```
scp -P 45688 codes.examples 'user@remote:~ahmet/'
```